# How to resolve: WPF access keys intercepted by IE

Tags: wpf, internet-explorer, keyboard-shortcuts, xbap, access-keys

We have built a XBAP application and have given the access keys (keyboard shortcuts) on labels/buttons. But IE seems to capture the access key first and hence the application does not get a chance to handle the access keys.

Is there any workaround/solution so that XBAP application overrides the access key of IE?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there are some access keys that IE will always catch first:

[From this link:](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/bde090af-4fa2-4cf5-89c3-b68e1484a261/)

"Unfortunately the reality is not all IE keyboard shortcuts can be intercepted, or even received by .xbaps.  This is because IE gets first crack at input coming to its window, regardless of who has focus.  If it chooses not to propagate a message, we can't do anything about it. "